# Landscape 16.06 security_update_db.sh Error

Tags: 16.04, server, proxy, landscape

I know that cron jobs don't work through the proxy, but when I try to manually run the security_update_db.sh via the command outlined here https://help.landscape.canonical.com/LDS/ValidationGuide

```
sudo -u landscape bash -x /opt/canonical/landscape/scripts/update_security_db.sh
```

The file downloads, but then I get an error when the script moves passed the downloading part.

```
+ output='  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 11.1M  100 11.1M    0     0   355k      0  0:00:32  0:00:32 --:--:--  315k'
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ mv -f /var/lib/landscape/usndb.pickle.bz2-new /var/lib/landscape/usndb.pickle.bz2
+ cd /opt/canonical/landscape
+ set -o pipefail
+ bzcat /var/lib/landscape/usndb.pickle.bz2
+ ./process-usns /dev/stdin
+ pipe_to_syslog update-security-db
+ tag=update-security-db
++ get_logger_arguments
++ echo /dev/log
++ grep -q :
++ '[' -n /dev/log ']'
++ '[' /dev/log '!=' /dev/log ']'
++ echo ''
+ args=
+ logger -s -p user.error -t update-security-db
<11>Feb  3 22:11:31 update-security-db: Traceback (most recent call last):
<11>Feb  3 22:11:31 update-security-db:   File "./process-usns", line 7, in <module>
<11>Feb  3 22:11:31 update-security-db:     canonical.landscape.scripts.usn.run()
<11>Feb  3 22:11:31 update-security-db:   File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/scripts/batch.py", line 66, in __call__
<11>Feb  3 22:11:31 update-security-db:     code = self.run()
<11>Feb  3 22:11:31 update-security-db:   File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/scripts/usn.py", line 40, in run
<11>Feb  3 22:11:31 update-security-db:     changeset = update_from_usn_tool_db(db)
<11>Feb  3 22:11:31 update-security-db:   File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/model/package/usn.py", line 195, in update_from_usn_tool_db
<11>Feb  3 22:11:31 update-security-db:     added=added_package_usns_map, removed=removed_package_usns_map)
<11>Feb  3 22:11:31 update-security-db:   File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/model/package/client.py", line 38, in query
<11>Feb  3 22:11:31 update-security-db:     return self._query(method, params)
<11>Feb  3 22:11:31 update-security-db:   File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/model/package/client.py", line 60, in _query
<11>Feb  3 22:11:31 update-security-db:     raise PackageSearchRequestError(loads(error.body)["Error"])
<11>Feb  3 22:11:31 update-security-db:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
<11>Feb  3 22:11:31 update-security-db:     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
<11>Feb  3 22:11:31 update-security-db:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
<11>Feb  3 22:11:31 update-security-db:     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
<11>Feb  3 22:11:31 update-security-db:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
<11>Feb  3 22:11:31 update-security-db:     raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
<11>Feb  3 22:11:31 update-security-db: ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
+ '[' 1 -ne 0 ']'
+ alert_admin update_security_db.sh
+ echo 'Error running /opt/canonical/landscape/scripts/update_security_db.sh: 0'
Error running /opt/canonical/landscape/scripts/update_security_db.sh: 0
+ echo 'Check out the syslog output for script update_security_db.sh.'
Check out the syslog output for script update_security_db.sh.
+ exit 1
+ release_lock update_security_db.sh
+ get_distributed_lock update_security_db.sh --release
+ local command=/opt/canonical/landscape/get-distributed-lock
+ /opt/canonical/landscape/get-distributed-lock update_security_db.sh --release
+ rm -f /var/lock/update_security.lock
```

Output from /var/log/landscape-server/security_update_db.log just repeats this over and over:

```
Feb  3 16:11:38 update-security-db ERR  Traceback (most recent call last):
Feb  3 16:11:38 update-security-db ERR    File "./process-usns", line 7, in <module>
Feb  3 16:11:38 update-security-db ERR      canonical.landscape.scripts.usn.run()
Feb  3 16:11:38 update-security-db ERR    File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/scripts/batch.py", line 66, in __call__
Feb  3 16:11:38 update-security-db ERR      code = self.run()
Feb  3 16:11:38 update-security-db ERR    File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/scripts/usn.py", line 40, in run
Feb  3 16:11:38 update-security-db ERR      changeset = update_from_usn_tool_db(db)
Feb  3 16:11:38 update-security-db ERR    File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/model/package/usn.py", line 195, in update_from_usn_tool_db
Feb  3 16:11:38 update-security-db ERR      added=added_package_usns_map, removed=removed_package_usns_map)
Feb  3 16:11:38 update-security-db ERR    File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/model/package/client.py", line 38, in query
Feb  3 16:11:38 update-security-db ERR      return self._query(method, params)
Feb  3 16:11:38 update-security-db ERR    File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/model/package/client.py", line 60, in _query
Feb  3 16:11:38 update-security-db ERR      raise PackageSearchRequestError(loads(error.body)["Error"])
Feb  3 16:11:38 update-security-db ERR    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
Feb  3 16:11:38 update-security-db ERR      return _default_decoder.decode(s)
Feb  3 16:11:38 update-security-db ERR    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
Feb  3 16:11:38 update-security-db ERR      obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
Feb  3 16:11:38 update-security-db ERR    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
Feb  3 16:11:38 update-security-db ERR      raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
Feb  3 16:11:38 update-security-db ERR  ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I do have a proxy setup and have configured environment variables with proxy info added to /etc/environment to /etc/apt/apt.conf to /etc/wgetrc as well as ~/curlrc

This allowed me to actually download https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn-db/database.pickle.bz2 but when it attempts to parse that is where it seems to fail. Anyone able to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this. After the scripts downloads the `https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn-db/database.pickle.bz2` via proxy the script is piping to webservice on localhost `HTTP: POST http://localhost:9099/UpdateUsns HTTP/1.1`

This one fails on proxy as the proxy server has no access to your localhost interface. The solution was to disable proxy for only this call. i.e.

Edit

```
/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/model/package/client.py
```

and change around line 56

```
response = self.fetch(url, post=True, data=data, total_timeout=60")
```

to

```
response = self.fetch(url, post=True, data=data, total_timeout=60, proxy="")
```

cheers / Thor

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution without changing the LDS source, set (or append) localhost to the `NO_PROXY` variable in `/etc/environment`:

```
HTTP_PROXY="..."
HTTPS_PROXY="..."
NO_PROXY="localhost"
```

All three variables will be sourced and exported by `/opt/canonical/landscape/scripts/landscape-env.py`, which the `update_security_db.sh` script (and all other cron job scripts) refer to.

(Tested on Landscape Dedicated Server 18.03.)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the rabbitmq is okay, because when it is down you get the 111 error as well when it attempts to process the downloaded file.

I had this same situation when rabbitmq was not running correctly and `rabbitmqctl status` was showing

```
Status of node rabbit@landscape
Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@landscape: nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@landscape]

rabbit@landscape:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on landscape
  * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
                  other nodes on landscape: ['rabbitmq-cli-55']
  * suggestion: start the node
```

But the command `rabbitmqctl start_app` was not starting it and giving an error:

```
Starting node rabbit@landscape
Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@landscape: nodedown
```

I found a report in a forum where clearing rabbitmq logs worked. I tried the following:

```
sudo service rabbitmq-server stop
sudo rm -rf /var/log/rabbitmq/*
sudo service rabbitmq-server start
```

After this I could `rabbitmqctl start_app` and the node came up. 
Manually calling the update_security_db script with `sudo -u landscape bash -x /opt/canonical/landscape/scripts/update_security_db.sh` now worked